# copyMerge method in apache-spark is running indefinitely

Tags: azure, apache-spark, blob, talend, azure-hdinsight

The following command is generated by a talend ETL tool 6.4.1
The command to merge all files was working fine all these days.
suddenly this command is running indefinitely.
The total size of files to be merged is 80GB.
Please help to find the root cause.
We are using apache spark HDinsight distribution
version 2.1.1.2.6.2.3-1
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_171

```
 org.talend.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copyMerge(fs,
                        sourceDirPath_tFileOutputDelimited_2, fs,
                        targetFilePath_tFileOutputDelimited_2, true, job, null,
                        headerByteCount_tFileOutputDelimited_2);
```

Comment: have you any error logs on HDFS side? Or either memory issues on your machine/cluster ?

Comment: I don't see any error in spark job log . Other jobs are getting completed succesfully.

Comment: @TomG Were you ever able to solve this error? For me in Talend 7.2.1, the files just don't get merged and I don't see any errors in the logs.

Comment: Hello 
@COR we were not able to solve this problem. The total size of the part files to be merged was 180GB. It seems spark has problem merging all these files. We however  removed all the old data( obsolete data) and was able to finally reduce the size of part files to 80 GB and it worked. Also the merging is a single thread operation ( not distributed) so either it takes lot of time or won't work like in our case.